# Is it possible to use a grid template like vaadin-grid to custom the "groups" column in vis.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, vaadin, vis.js, vaadin-grid

I want to know if it's possible to use a grid template (like vaadin-grid) to custom the "groups" column in vis.js (put images, links...) ? I haven't found any example on the net...

Answer (score 0):

There are no templates, however you can personalize the "groups" column using the property `groupTemplate` in the timeline options (http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options).

You can see a example in the official examples:
http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/groupsEditable.html